# Data Annotations Fails

Tags: c#, data-annotations

In my c# class i am decorating a property with data annotations for validating 5 digit number. The number must be of min and max of 5 digits in length. But it is always saying not valid. What wrong with my regular expression?

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{5})\)$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (GlobalErrorResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "QUOTEREQUEST_VALID_ZIP_CODE")]
```

Comment: Do you have `[Required]` attribute with `[RegularExpression]` ?

Comment: The problem is your regular expression matches literal parenthesis `(` `)` but you never stated that you wanted to do so.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, can u explain in detail pls, i cant understand

Comment: @SSS I've added an answer that should actually explain what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding `/ /` is used in JavaScript .

Try this regular expression `@"^(\d{5})$"`

**\d** if for **[0-9]** group

**{5}** as you know length required.

**{1,5}** you can it, if you want to specify minimum (1) and maximum (5) length.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this expression

```
"^[0-9]{5,5}$"
```

Comment: +1, thanks for the different idea... can you explain this expression pls ?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression:

```
      |-------------- start of group 1
      v        v----- end   of group 1
@"^\(?([0-9]{5})\)$"
  ^^ ^   ^   ^  ^ ^-- end of line
  || |   |   |  |---- literal right parenthesis ")"
  || |   |   |------- match 5 times
  || |   |----------- match characters '0' thru '9'
  || |--------------- non-greedy match (I believe)
  ||----------------- literal left parenthesis  "("
  |------------------ start of line
```

Do you actually want to be matching parentheses, like "(12345)" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own attribute for this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ZipAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public ZipAttribute() : base("\\A\\b[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?\\b\\z")
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid ZIP code.";
    }
}
```

To use it, you will need to add a line to your `Global.asax`

```
 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(ZipAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Zip code of 5 or 9 digit

```
    [Display(Name = "Zipcode"), RegularExpression("[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?", ErrorMessage="Zipcode must be in the proper format: '12345' or '12345-6789'")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{5}")]
```

When you put **\(**, you are indicating that you have to add the brackets to place the zip code.